# How to set the metadata hop count for fargate instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I want to run some C# code on a Fargate instance, that uses the 'current' user/role.

In my code, I set the default AWS options:

```
awsOptions.Credentials = new InstanceProfileAWSCredentials();
services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(awsOptions);
```

This then tries to access the metadata server to get the credentials that the instance is running under.  My Task has "sts:GetCallerIdentity" permission.

This is not working.

```
Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException: Unable to reach credentials server
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Invalid argument (169.254.169.254:80)
```

It appears that the new IMDSv2 metadata server [requires](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html) the hop count to be 2. All the examples use CLI.

Q) How do I do this, using Terraform?

Comment: Do you have any terraform code?

Comment: @MarkoE Yes.  I have everything up and running using Terraform, it's just this last hurdle that I need to fix.

Comment: The question said you want to do it with terraform, however there is no terraform code in the question.

Comment: @MarkoE Correct, because I have no idea what Terraform module to use to configure this.  I could post my 20,000 line TF file, but that doesn't contain anything related to the problem, which is how to set the TTL to the media service.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Fargate is a **serverless** solution for Amazon ECS - container service. What you're trying to do is to set a configuration for Amazon EC2 instance, in order to do so you need to run container environment on a EC2 instance directly!
This means terraform can't help you with your intentions.

If you are looking how to use metadata endpoint inside ECR, check that out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v4.html

Comment: I believe you,  but what you are implying is that Fargate cannot follow AWS best practices, and must pass the access/secret key via environment variables., which is deprecated?

Comment: Not sure how it’s related to hop count. You should always use IAM Policy or Role, both can be set for the service. If you are looking to use metadata endpoint check that out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v4.html

Comment: Why you need to obtain credentials, rather than use IAM?

Comment: In the link in my question, there's a section called Considerations where it mentions the 2 hop requirement (and it's mentioned in other SO questions).  I am using MassTransit, and there is a requirement to pass in AWSCredentials, I want to use the credentials for the Task the service is running under, the recommendation is to use InstanceProfileAWSCredentials, but I think it's failing because the Metadata service is unreachable.